# Am I supposed to be reviewing spam flags?

Tags: bug, review, chat, flags, spam

I was just chatting in chat when I saw a little ping-like circle except it was blue and on the wrong side.

[image: Blue chat ping]

So I did what any good citizen would do and I clicked it. It quickly prompted me to review a chat message that was flagged.

[image: message saying that the chat message was flagged spam/offensive]

I tried searching Meta for information on reviewing chat flags and if that is a privilege afforded certain users at certain rep levels and I found nothing. Is this intended behavior? Similar to review queues? Offensive flags seem a bit on the moderator side of things but I am uncertain.

Comment: Regarding the dupe: _"When you flag a message as spam/offensive, the flag will draw the attention of every moderator and user with >10k reputation currently on the chat network. In both cases, they’ll be asked to determine if the flag is valid or not"_ You do have 10k rep network-wide (congrats!), so yep, these pop up for you